# Ansible Variable Looping

Tags: loops, variables, ansible

I'm very new to ansible and was having issues with variable inheritance/looping within my playbook.  The playbook is used to configure vxlan vrfs and vxlan vlans for some Cisco leafs.

Here are the variables:

```
   username: admin
   password: password
   transport: cli

   vrfmember: DMZ_TOOLS
   vlan: 1000 ##starts here
   vlanname: DMZ_TOOLS_01
   vnsegment: 1000000
   mcastgroup: 225.1.1.1
   description: DMZ Tools Network 1
   ipaddress: 10.1.1.1/26    
   vlan: 1001 ##switches here
   vlanname: DMZ_TOOLS_02
   vnsegment: 1000001
   mcastgroup: 225.1.1.2
   description: DMZ Tools Network 2
   ipaddress: 10.1.1.2/26
```

Here is the playbook:

```
---
- name: meme
  hosts: all
  connection: local

  vars_files:
    - /root/ansible/examples/playbooks/vars_shit.yml

  tasks:

    - name: vlan config (vrf edition)
      nxos_command:
        commands:
          - conf t
          - vlan {{ vlan }}
          - name {{ vlanname }}
          - vn-segment {{ vnsegment }}
        provider: "{{ cli }}"

    - name: vrf config
      nxos_command:
        commands:
          - conf t
          - vrf context {{ vlanname }}
          - vni {{ vnsegment }}
          - rd auto
          - address-family ipv4 unicast
          - route-target both auto
          - route-target both auto evpn
        provider: "{{ cli }}"

    - name: int vlan
      nxos_command:
        commands:
          - conf t
          - interface {{ vlan }}
          - description {{ description }}
          - no shutdown
          - vrf member {{ vrfmember }}
          - no ip redirects
          - ip forward
          - no ipv6 redirects
        provider: "{{ cli }}"

    - name: int nve1
      nxos_command:
        commands:
          - conf t
          - member vni {{ vnsegment }}
        provider: "{{ cli }}"

    - name: router shit stoof
      nxos_command:
        commands:
          - conf t
          - router bgp 65490
          - vrf {{ vrfmember }}
          - address-family ipv4 unicast
          - advertise 12vpn evpn
        provider: "{{ cli }}"

    - name: vlan config
      nxos_command:
        commands:
          - conf t
          - vlan {{ vlan }}
          - name {{ vlanname }}
          - vn-segment {{ vnsegment }}
        provider: "{{ cli }}"

    - name: interface config
      nxos_command:
        commands:
          - conf t
          - interface nve1
          - member vni {{ vnsegment }}
          - suppress-arp
          - mcast-group {{ mcastgroup }}
        provider: "{{ cli }}"

    - name: evpn config
      nxos_command:
        commands:
          - conf t
          - evpn
          - vni {{ vnsegment }} l2
          - rd auto
          - route-target import auto
          - route-target export auto
        provider: "{{ cli }}"

    - name: int vlan config
      nxos_command:
        commands:
          - conf t
          - interface vlan {{ vlan }}
          - description {{ description }}
          - no shutdown
          - mtu 9216
          - vrf member {{ vrfmember }}
          - no ip redirects
          - ip address {{ ipaddress }}
          - no ipv6 redirects
          - fabric forwarding mode anycast-gateway
        provider: "{{ cli }}"
```

I'm trying to have the first set of cisco variables to be passed through and once it finishes at "ipaddress" it would switch over to the 2nd set of variables.
Sorry about the formatting, but any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create something like this

```
   username: admin
   password: password
   transport: cli

   interface:
     - vrfmember: DMZ_TOOLS
       vlan: 1000 ##starts here
       vlanname: DMZ_TOOLS_01
       vnsegment: 1000000
       mcastgroup: 225.1.1.1
       description: DMZ Tools Network 1
       ipaddress: 10.1.1.1/26    
     - vlan: 1001 ##switches here
       vlanname: DMZ_TOOLS_02
       vnsegment: 1000001
       mcastgroup: 225.1.1.2
       description: DMZ Tools Network 2
       ipaddress: 10.1.1.2/26
```

and then loop over it with something like

```
with_items:
  - '{{ interface }}'
```

and access your variables inside your tasks with

```
{{ item.vnsegment }}
```

And you probably want to execute all three tasks with the first item of `interface` and then with the second, so you can get your tasks in a `.yml` file called `do_stuff.yml` and then include it with

```
- include: do_stuff.yml
  with_items:
    - '{{ interface }}'
```

This will allow you to execute a group of tasks for a group of configurations. To make it a bit easier to understand, if you unroll ansibles loop with the `do_stuff.yml` approach, the tasks that will be executed are going to be:

```
- name: vlan config (vrf edition) // with interface[0]
- name: vrf config // with interface[0]
- name: int vlan // with interface[0]
- name: int nve1 // with interface[0]
- name: router shit stoof // with interface[0]
- name: vlan config // with interface[0]
- name: interface config // with interface[0]
- name: evpn config // with interface[0]
- name: int vlan config // with interface[0]
- name: vlan config (vrf edition) // with interface[1]
- name: vrf config // with interface[1]
- name: int vlan // with interface[1]
- name: int nve1 // with interface[1]
- name: router shit stoof // with interface[1]
- name: vlan config // with interface[1]
- name: interface config // with interface[1]
- name: evpn config // with interface[1]
- name: int vlan config // with interface[1]
```

If you dont do the do_stuff.yml but just add a `with_items` in your tasks, the unrolled loop will look like

```
- name: vlan config (vrf edition) // with interface[0]
- name: vlan config (vrf edition) // with interface[1]
- name: vrf config // with interface[0]
- name: vrf config // with interface[1]
```

Comment: i've added more infos on the later part of the answer with an example. let me know if it helps @ConfusedSQLStudent